# Share touch events in ListView

Tags: android, listview

In a vertical ListView that also needs to do drag and drop in the horizontal direction, I'm listening for ACTION_MOVE events, looking for the appropriate deltaX. It works all right unless the ListView also starts scrolling vertically. As soon as it starts doing so, it consumes the move events and my drag and drop handler doesn't get a chance.

`requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` is not the solution, for two reasons. First, I don't want to disable scrolling, I just want to share the move events so that **both** handlers can see them. Second, I don't even reach to the point to issue this because scrolling already consumes the events before it would reach my horizontal threshold for action.

Is there any viable solution short of overriding and overwriting the ListView event interceptor?

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
  switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)) {
    ...
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      if (!isDragging) {
        float deltaX = Math.abs(downX - event.getX());
          if (deltaX > touchSlop) {
            isDragging = true;
            view.startDrag(...);
          }
        }
        return true;
    }

   return false;
  }
});
```

Bog standard. It works when the user moves horizontally, ACTION_MOVEs come in, dragging starts when required. It doesn't when the user also moves vertically, even if just slightly, because the ListView intercepts all ACTION_MOVEs during scrolling and I never get a deltaX large enough to start the actual dragging operation.

Comment: so you'd like to drag n drop _while_ the list is scrolling ?

Comment: Yes. I want to start the drag if the deltaX is large enough, no matter whether there is or isn't a vertical scrolling at the same time.

To visualize, imagine the list to contain small images. I want to be able to drag one to the center of the screen. And I want to be able to do that even if the image the user starts with is not adjacent to the center of the screen but above or below, so the drag motion from the image to the screen center will have a vertical component as well.

Comment: Why don't you call [startDrag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startDrag) when u decide to start a drag, as explained in [android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: Or you mean you don't receive `ACTION_MOVE` as scrolling starts ? Perhaps in that case you could start drag `onLongClick` followed by `ACTION_MOVE` ?

Comment: I call startDrag() when I can, of course. But I only can call it if I can learn that it's time to start the dragging. If the ListView consumes the MOVE events and I'm not even called, I can't start the drag... Long click would be a good solution theoretically and technically but unfortunately, from a UI experience point of view, it's no good to me. I need simple drags without a preceding long click, that's what the user would expect here.

Answer (score 1):

Bit the bullet. It only really works with extending, no other way:

```
public class DraggableListView extends ListView {
  private float diffX = 0, diffY = 0;
  private float lastX = 0, lastY = 0;

  public DraggableListView(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
  }

  public DraggableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public DraggableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        diffX = 0;
        diffY = 0;
        lastX = event.getX();
        lastY = event.getY();
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        diffX += Math.abs(event.getX() - lastX);
        diffY += Math.abs(event.getY() - lastY);
        lastX = event.getX();
        lastY = event.getY();
        if (diffX > diffY)
          return false;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
  }
}
```